# VPS openssh connect problem, How i can access my vps?

Tags: centos7, vps

I have a vps, where have a centos 7 operation system. Unfortunately I open a firewall and block openssh and ftp. Now I can not access my vps. Now how I can access my vps?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you must connect to the server through the console or VNC.
Ask where you bought this server to give you console or VNC access. If you have virtualized yourself, enter the operating system of the virtualizer and connect to the server through that and turn off the firewall.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't connect to your server online and you got it from a provider, you can ask them to request console access so that you can easily enter your server and change your settings, and if you don't know it, you can Ask your provider's support to reset the server settings. If you don't have important information on your server, the easiest way is to request a server reinstall.